# Swipe gesture not working on UIPageViewController when button clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I have created a `UIPageViewController` which I present on the screen.

The page view consists of 4 views. On top of each view I have added a `UIButton` over the top of the whole view to detect when someone clicks on a view.

Here is the view in interface builder. The whole of each coloured view has a button covering it:

[image]

When the user swipes I want the page view controller to go from one screen to the next.

**Problem**

When I go to make a swipe gesture, if I touch a button then it picks up the tap gesture for that button. So if I continue to slide my finger across the screen the page gesture doesn't work.

**Goal**

Even when I tap on a `UIButton`, if I don't lift my finger but instead make a swipe gesture, then I would like the `UIPageViewController` to turn page.

How can I override the touch gesture and instead make the slide gesture count and thus turn the page of the `UIPageViewController`.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: You should add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to each of your 4 views instead of using `UIButton`. That should be enough to fix your problem, but you can additionally implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol if you need to, and act as delegate for all the gesture recognisers.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Many thanks.